# ExecuteReader on Oracle with joins

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, oracle10g

I m using oracle express 10g2 with .net connector (oracle.dataaccess.dll).

My problem is I've 2 tables joinable A and B;

in sqlDeveloper i call that:

```
select * from A; //no problem
select * from B; // no problem
select * from A inner join B on B.id = A.bId; // no problem + joining
```

my c# class (LocalOracleDataProvider.cs);

```
var cm1 = connection.CreateCommand();
cm1.CommandText = "select * from A;";
var cm2 = connection.CreateCommand();
cm2.CommandText = "select * from B;";
var cm3 = connection.CreateCommand();
cm3.CommandText = "select * from A inner join B on B.id = A.bId;";
...
var dt1 = cm1.ExecuteReader(); // ok
var dt2 = cm2.ExecuteReader(); // ok
var dt3 = cm3.ExecuteReader(); // crash oracle error ORA-00911 : invalid character
```

i don't understand the problem ...
is it error requesting of mine i did not see?
or is there any issue about it (did not found one -- am i alone on this?)?
must i create a sqlview encapsulating the join request?
or any other bypass?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Take out the first ;  "select * from A inner join B on B.id = A.bId";

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the third command to:

```
cm3.CommandText = "select * from A inner join B on ( B.id = A.bId ) ;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the semicolons at the end of your sql statements.
In SELECTs statements semicolon are not allowed, but in other statements like CALLs and EXECUTSs they are required.

Also, this is probably redundant, but add a

```
cm3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it ... ExecuteReader is not compatible with ";"

Comment: I don't think it is ExecuteReader the culprit, but the Oracle Engine that doesn't understand that semicolon at the end of the statement.